# How do I list or search all the column names in my database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, metadata

I want to search for a string in the names of the columns present in a database.

I’m working on a maintenance project and some of the databases I deal with have more than 150 tables, so I'm looking for a quick way to do this.

What do you recommend?

Comment: similar question asked in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql/548086#548086)

Comment: good article. Thanks a lot. I also used TM Field Finder and it's really powerfull in matter of search in SQL Schema and also data.

Comment: Related: *[Exploring your database schema with SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/exploring-your-database-schema-with-sql/)*

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use following query to list all columns or search columns across tables in a database.

```
USE AdventureWorks 
GO 
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

You can make use of  [information_schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) views to list all objects in SQL Server 2005 or 2008 databases.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables

SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/06/sql-server-query-to-find-column-from-all-tables-of-database/

Comment: Thanks, did what I need. I was just curious about how many columns were in the database, and this gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

There is also [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) - a free tool that integrates with SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

Comment: SQL Search is a good tool, but keep in mind that the results window is arbitrarily limited to, I believe, 250 results.  The last time I used this tool, Red Gate did not have a way of lifting this limitation.  That having been said, it is still a very useful tool and I would recommend it to any SQL Server DBA or Developer.  The price is right too!

Answer (score 5):

Late one but hopefully useful since both tools are free.

[ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) – good thing about this tool is that it can also search data, show dependencies between objects and couple other useful things.

[image]

[SSMS Toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=5) – free for all versions except SQL 2012. A lot of great options that are not related only to searching such as snippets, various customizations and more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one that all SQL DBA from old time use.

```
EXEC sp_help 'your table name';
```

If only with single line, you don't even need to type EXEC. Just do

```
sp_help 'your table name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to search all the databases and tell you which database has a table.column:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SET @command =
'USE ? IF EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
where t.name = ''TableName'' 
and c.name = ''ColumnName''
) select ''?'''
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: note sp_MSforeachdb has some issues where dbs will be missed https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/